# How can I deploy dkms Debian modules built during a build process?

Tags: dkms

I'm debating if I should put `dkms` on production machines along with all the build tools it requires.  Seems like there might be security issues, or at the least added bloat when provisioning a new machine.

I don't know if there's a way to use a CI system to make the modules, then deploy them to a machine running the target kernel.  Are there commands or configuration built into `dkms` to help facilitate this usage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `dkms` [supports this scenario](https://github.com/dell/dkms/blob/master/README.md#installation-on-systems-with-no-module-source-andor-compiler). You need to have the appropriate kernel and headers installed on the CI system; then install the `dkms` module you want to ship, and run

```
dkms mktarball
```

with the appropriate module and version. Copy the resulting tarball to the target systems, and load it with

```
dkms ldtarball /path/to/dkmstarball
```

This will install the binary modules and make them available.

For Debian specifically, you can also create a Debian package containing pre-built modules, using

```
dkms mkdeb
```

with the appropriate module and version. See [the `dkms` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/dkms) and [HOWTO](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dkms/blob/master/debian/HOWTO.Debian) for details.